# Don't know how to apply raster to every planet in my code

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to draw planets on my canvas following a basic example on **paper.js** website, but when I want to use a raster in a for loop to apply "texture" to every one of them, only one planet gets the texture.

I've tried a couple solutions online, but none of them allowed me to make what I'm looking for. You will notice that, in my code, I have both planets (Points) and stars (Stars). The texture is a basic 100*100 square image.

```
        var url = '../IMG/planettexture.png';
        var raster = new Raster(url);

        var count = 150;
        var x = window.innerWidth;
        var y = window.innerHeight;

        for (i=0;i<count;i++){

            var xrandom = randomCoordinates(x);
            var yrandom = randomCoordinates(y);

            var center = new Point(xrandom,yrandom);

            var points = 12;

            var radius1 = randomCoordinates(1);
            var radius2 = randomCoordinates(5);
            var path = new Path.Star(center, points, radius1, radius2);
            path.fillColor = 'white';

            raster.position = new Point(xrandom,yrandom);
            path.clipMask = true;
        }

        var path = new Path.Circle({
            center: [0, 0],
            radius: 10,
            fillColor: 'white',
            strokeColor: 'black'
        });

        var symbol = new Symbol(path);

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var center = Point.random() * view.size;
            var placedSymbol = symbol.place(center);
            placedSymbol.scale(i / count);
        }

        function randomCoordinates(number){
            return Math.random()*number;
        }

        function onFrame(event) {

        for (var i = 0; i < 450; i++) {
            var item = project.activeLayer.children[i];

            item.position.x += item.bounds.width / 20;

            if (item.bounds.left > view.size.width) {
               item.position.x = -item.bounds.width;
            }
        }
    }
```

You need Paper.js to run this.
With this code, only one Star is "textured", the rest isn't visible on my screen. Do you have any idea where the problem is coming from ?

Comment: check your usage of  `var raster = new Raster(url);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you need to clone your raster inside the for loop ?

```
var clonedRaster = raster.clone();
clonedRaster.position = new Point(xrandom,yrandom);
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/JulienLemaitre/pen/PMmBNJ

Comment: I did that, but now I only have the first raster outside of the for loop, and not the cloned one on my screen.

Comment: `path.clipMask = true;` doesn't work. Try without it.

Also, you are mixing stars and planet raster in your for loop, so they end up at the same coordinates (that doesn't prevent them from being displayed)

Comment: I've added an example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you ! It's working nicely. I'm going to study that and improve my code.

Comment: One quick question : do you know why I just have one planet displayed with no error in my console with your code ? I've changed the canvasID and I only have that canvas in my HTML file, stars are fine but not the planet.

Comment: Non, I don't know. I see the same on CodePen. When I refresh the page, it display all the planets though.

Comment: I figured it out ! I had to reassign the source URL in the for loop for it to work. Thanks again !